# toggle class on function output in vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I want to render the content of `requestData` to `li` elements
each list item gets a onclick function
which if the li element is clicked(selected) adds a specific value from a ref to an array
later if clicked again(unselected) delets the item /

how can I combine the function output `true` / `false`
to `:class="{ selected: requestData }"`  to add or remove the class if selected/unselected

```
<template>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="item in requestData.items"
        :key="item.id"
        :class="{ selected: requestData }"
        @click="getSelectedElemData($event.target)"
      >
        {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, ref } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import items from "../assets/comp.Data/items.json";

export default {
  setup() {
    let requestData = ref(items);
   
    let selectedElements = [];


    function getSelectedElemData(target) {
    

      for (let element of requestData._rawValue.items) {
        if (target.innerText === element.name) {
          console.log(element);
          // Add to calc
          // update the selectedElements array
          selectedElements.push(element);
          console.log(selectedElements);

          return true;
        }
      }
    }

    return {
      requestData,
      getSelectedElemData,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: so what you are saying is if a list item is selected in selectedElements you want that li to have selected class and remove the class if it is not selected?

Comment: yes exactly this needs to be individually for each element

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this apporach and call **isItemSelected** function for each element. If the item is included in the list, class we added to the li otherwise it will be removed. And change the isItemSelected function accordingly to your current data set, below approach it is for array of objects.

```
<template>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="item in requestData.items"
        :key="item.id"
        :class="{ 'selected': isItemSelected(item) }"
        @click="getSelectedElemData($event.target)"
      >
        {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, ref } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import items from "../assets/comp.Data/items.json";

export default {
  setup() {
    let requestData = ref(items);
   
    let selectedElements = [];

    function getSelectedElemData(target) {
    
      for (let element of requestData._rawValue.items) {
        if (target.innerText === element.name) {
          console.log(element);
          // Add to calc
          // update the selectedElements array
          selectedElements.push(element);
          console.log(selectedElements);

          return true;
        }
      }
    }

   function isItemSelected(item){
     return selectedElements.find(element=>element.id===item.id)
   }

    return {
      requestData,
      isItemSelected,
      getSelectedElemData
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: this was also my idea but using function outputs in `:class` seems not to work

Comment: Try inspecting the dom in your browser and see if the class gets attached or not.